# Podio Api filter offset doesn't seem to be working

Tags: podio

I am trying to migrate comments from some 2000 items into another app. I know the filter has a limit of 500 records. I am passing an offset like the documentation says:

https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/filter-items-4496747

Here's the code:

```
$collection = PodioItem::filter(config('podio.content_app_id'),[
            'limit' => 500,
            'offset' => $offset,
            'sort_by' => 'created_on',
            'sort_desc' => true
        ]);
```

the offset changes in a while loop and I know it is incrementing.

The app I am getting the collections from has 1200, but every request I make has 500 records and they are pretty much the same ( which is odd).

I make 5 requests with incremental offsets and I only get 504 unique item ids. Am I missing something?

Thanks,

Rico

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd be doing that in **Ruby**

```
options = {'limit' => 100, 'offset' => 0}
filter = {:last_edit_on => {:from => '-7d', :to => '+0d'}}      # as example, work with most recent items only
all_found_items = []
result = Podio::Item.find_by_filter_values(app_id, filter, options)
puts "Found #{result.count} items matching filter #{filter}"
all_found_items += result.all

while all_found_items.length < result.count
  options['offset'] = all_found_items.length
  result = Podio::Item.find_by_filter_values(app.app_id, filter, options)
  all_found_items += result.all
end

all_found_items.each_with_index do |item, i|
  puts "\t#{i+1}: #{item.title}"
end
```

And it worked great when I fetched thousands of items.

Comment: The php api shows the call like this: **PodioItem::filter( $app_id, $attributes = array(), $options = array() );** What are the **attributes** and what are the **options**? Maybe that is my problem

Comment: Have you tried using $options to store limit and offset, and $attributes for filter values?